# Beta test for short survey in banner ad slots starting on the week of November 13th on SO [Beta has ended]

Tags: support, advertising, announcement

**[EDIT: This beta has now ended.]**

**TL;DR:** Starting on the week of November 13th, we will be showing a short survey in the banner ad slots on Stack Overflow. Note - the announcement for the alpha version of this test was posted on MSE ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393130/alpha-test-for-short-survey-in-banner-ad-slots-starting-on-week-of-september-25t)) thus the duplicate text (with minor variations).

### What is this survey about?

The survey is meant to provide better insight for customers (companies who pay to advertise with us) into how users' sentiment towards their company or its products and services are affected by advertising on Stack Overflow. It is an optional survey, in which we'll ask some users questions about a company so we can test and measure whether their ads have had any impact on the user's perception of that brand. Not all users who see an ad will be served the survey, and we only survey users that are opted-in to targeting cookies. Responses are completely anonymous and no personal information from the respondents will be collected or stored.

### Where will it be shown, and what does it look like?

We explored a few different options for conducting the survey, and ended up deciding to use the existing banner ad slots for these — meaning you'll see the ads and the banner in the same placement (though not at the same time, just to clarify). This seemed like the simplest and less disruptive solution because it uses an existing placement that users already are accustomed to for ads, and also allows us to conduct the survey on-site without needing to prompt the user to fill it in on a third-party website. Here's what it'll look like (click to see full-sized version):

[image: Question page showing the survey in the banner ad slot, as described in the post. The survey asks the question "Which brands have you seen advertising for recently?" and provides a list of 5 companies plus a "none of these" option.]

### What sites will this be shown on?

This survey will only be shown on Stack Overflow

### Why are you telling us about this? Isn't this just an ad in the usual ad placement anyway?

This survey is both a new onsite survey, and a new usage of the banner ad slot. Since the conjunction of those two factors could lead to some confusion, we thought it would be better to let folks know that we were doing it in advance. In addition, the [previous alpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393130/alpha-test-for-short-survey-in-banner-ad-slots-starting-on-week-of-september-25t) was all in-house, while the beta will involve external clients.

The new survey will be going through this beta test, which will help inform our product decisions in the future, as well as let us work out any bugs or technical issues. We will let you know about next steps for this feature by updating this post or posting a new question for it.

If you see things breaking, please report those in the usual channels, or as an answer to this post.

Comment: How does this new "banner ad" interact [with ad reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) and adblockers? Oh, and ACME, Wonka, and, less recently, Stark -- and, waaaay less recently, SC, though they're now Sterling Cooper & Partners, right?

Comment: @ruffin The new banner ad will not show to those with the ad reduction privilege, nor to users with adblockers.

Comment: Thanks for telling us about this test!